# Redirect to page when a URL path pattern is identified

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'd like any traffic that comes to:

```
mysite.com/suppliers/add-supplier
```

To be directed to `add-supplier.html` when the path is identified in my `firebase.json` config file. I've tried this:

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "redirects": [
      {
        "source": "/suppliers/add-supplier",
        "destination": "/add-supplier.html"
      }
    ],
    "cleanUrls": true
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

Even though this identifies and redirects correctly, it gets rid of the `suppliers/add-supplier` path and makes it `mysite.com/add-supplier`

Is there a way to retain the original URL while also redirecting to the correct HTML page?

Comment: `"destination": "/suppliers/add-supplier.html"` perhaps?

Comment: @Phil tried that but it simply navigates to that path but not the actual html page. So it ends up in a 404

Comment: Sounds like you don't want a redirect at all then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use a rewrite instead of a redirect:

```json
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/suppliers/add-supplier",
    "destination": "/add-supplier.html"
  },
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

2. Remove the redirect entirely, and place your file at `suppliers/add-supplier.html` instead of in the root

Comment: Thank you. The first method redirects correctly but gets rid of the URL paths and ends up with `mysite.com/add-supplier`. How would I go about the 2nd method: after moving the page to a folder called 'suppliers', do I make it a rewrite or a redirect?

Comment: Awesome. Method 2 worked! I posted my updated answer. But I'll accept your answer cos you gave me the idea! :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I combined @samthecodingman's answer with some changes and got it working:

**Moved page to new directory**

I moved the `add-supplier.html` file to a new folder called `suppliers` inside the public directory so that it's `suppliers/add-supplier.html`

**firebase.json:**

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/suppliers/add-supplier",
        "destination": "suppliers/add-supplier.html"
      }
    ],
    "cleanUrls": true
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

This will correctly load the page but the CSS, media and JS files will not be identified. To fix this, change all your resource files to have `../` in the front:

before changing: `<link href="dist/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

after changing: `<link href="../dist/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`